# Ant build file not excluding other source directories

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

I'm new to ant. I'm trying to get my build.xml file to only build files from one package and not another. My project structure (simplified) is as follows

PROJECT
--Package A
--Package B

I only want ant to build java files from package A and not from package B.

In the auto-generated build.xml file from the Android SDK it says:

```
<!-- The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
     'android' tool to add properties to it.
     This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
     Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

     source.dir
         The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
     out.dir
         The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

     For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
     files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

     Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
     be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

     This file is an integral part of the build system for your
     application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

     -->
```

I added

```
<property name="source.dir" value="src/path/to/package/A" />
```

but it's still including Package B. What am I doing wrong?